# FTP upload returns 530 on Debian/Google Compute Engine, works ok on local Windows

Tags: ftp, google-compute-engine

I am uploading a file to an FTP server via a node.js script. Everything works fine on my Windows machine, but once I run the script on a Compute Engine instance, I get *Login incorrect.*

Since it works ok on a different machine, I suspect it must be a compute engine setting that messes up the connection.

Running the script with *sudo* doesn't help.

*iptables* are empty

Firewall rules in the Cloud Console are set to allow all ingress and egress
traffic, on all protocols/ports, all targets.

I am out of ideas where to look and will be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - When reposting there, include log files to back your claims.

Comment: Hi, should I delete this even when it has an answer? I did the repost.

Answer (score 0):

FTP `530` error code indicates that there was issue logging in to the remote FTP server using the provided credentials (i.e. username and password).

[`530   Not logged in.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

- Since you actually get a 530 error, it indicates you do not have any egress firewall issue for your connection from the GCE VM to your remote FTP server.
- If the script works fine on your Windows machine, ensure the script is not pulling credentials from a location accessible only on your Windows machine.
- Also, you can use any command line FTP client directly on your Google Compute Engine instance and verify if you are able to login to the remote FTP server using your credentials. If this works, you will have to debug and verify if the credentials used by the script are the same.